# Messaging in app conversation status

Tags: sdk

I'm trying to implement the messaging-in-app SDK in an Android application, right now I am implementing get the conversations with the function `coreClient.conversations(...)` in iOS I can see a SMIConversationStatus with the options (UNKNOWN, OPEN, CLOSED), but in Android, I can't found a param in the conversation that covers this same functionality, do this param exist in Android?